# Javascript invoke methods from another classes with common parameters

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Hello I struggle with the logical organization of code in my project.

I encountered a certain challenge, I have to check database table with some time interval of time if there are any new actions to be performed. Actions can be different and their logic is not related to each other, so I wanted to separate the code of each action into separate files.

I created an example files structure and I think it works the way I would like. I just wonder if it is a good thing that I am passing an instance of the database every time I call a   `await action.invoke(this.databaseInstance)` function repeatedly?

My files:

```
// index.js
const { Lion } = require('./Lion');

const databaseInstance = {
  database: 'Postgress',
  dialect: 'SQL'
};

const actionrunner = new Lion({ databaseInstance });
actionrunner.startProcessing();
```

```
// Lion.js
const { reoccuringActions } = require('./reoccuringActions');

class Lion {
  constructor({ databaseInstance }) {
    this.interval = 10000;
    this.intervalId = null;
    this.databaseInstance = databaseInstance;
  }

  startProcessing() {
    this.recuringInvoke();
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.recuringInvoke.bind(this), this.interval);
  }

  async recuringInvoke() {
    for (const action of reoccuringActions) {
      await action.invoke(this.databaseInstance);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = { Lion };
```

```
// reoccuringActions.js
const { BabyLion } = require('./babyLion');
const { BabyCat } = require('./babyCat');

const reoccuringActions = [new BabyLion(), new BabyCat()];

module.exports = { reoccuringActions };
```

```
// babyLion.js
class BabyLion {
  constructor() {}
  async invoke(databaseInstance) {
    console.log('invoke BabyLion');
    // do something
  }
}

module.exports = { BabyLion };
```

```
//babyCat.js
class BabyCat {
  constructor() {}
  async invoke(databaseInstance) {
    console.log('invoke babyCat');
    // do something
  }
}

module.exports = { BabyCat };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i don't think there is anything wrong with passing "databaseInstance" every time. But if you want to do in another way you can create "databaseInstance" as variable in each of your action and pass "databaseInstance" in constructor of your action. and use it there, in that way you don't have to pass every time.

```
// babyLion.js
class BabyLion {
  
  constructor({databaseInstance}) {
     this.databaseInstance;
  }
  async invoke() {
    console.log('invoke BabyLion');
    // do something
  }
}

module.exports = { BabyLion };


//babyCat.js
class BabyCat {
   constructor({databaseInstance}) {
     this.databaseInstance;
  }
  async invoke() {
    console.log('invoke babyCat');
    // do something
  }
}

module.exports = { BabyCat };


// reoccuringActions.js
const { BabyLion } = require('./babyLion');
const { BabyCat } = require('./babyCat');

const databaseInstance = require("FromSomewhere");

const reoccuringActions = [
           new BabyLion(databaseInstance), 
           new BabyCat(databaseInstance)
];

module.exports = { reoccuringActions };
```